# How can I make sublime looks like atom theme?

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

I'm looking to get the atom's default theme to import it into sublime text 3, if that's possible. I'm looking especially for the color scheme, any tips or source code would be appreciated, ty!

Comment: Do you have Package Control installed?

Comment: Of course buddy ;)

Comment: I would recommend installing the [`Materialize`](https://github.com/saadq/Materialize) package. (Disclaimer: It's my own package). It is basically a collections of themes for many color schemes. Atom's `One Dark` is included. So after installing `Materialize`, you can change your `theme` to `Material One Dark` and change your `color scheme` to `Material One Dark`. Edit: There is also the `One Dark Material Theme` mentioned below which I didn't know about, so you can just install that and you won't have all the extra themes from Materialize.

Comment: This is what I was thinking before. Gonna try this and come back with updates ;)

Comment: @Saad Materialize is AMAZING MaashAllah sooo happy I found it!

Answer (score 5):

Find a theme on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search/atom).

There is a [One Dark Material Theme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/One%20Dark%20Material%20-%20Theme) which looks like Atom, but I haven't used it myself.

[Boxy Theme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Boxy%20Theme) is very good, I use it myself, the Monokai Boxy variation is good. You can make look similar to atom.

Comment: I've tried this theme but find there are some differences with Atom. For example, the left hand side of keyword arguments are not orange, but red (like "self").

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Theme - One Dark](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20One%20Dark) (it works for both Sublime Text 2 and Sublime Text 3)

### Installation Steps

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the [Command Palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html).
2. Type *Install Package* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd>.
3. Search for *Theme - One Dark* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd>.

### Configuration Steps

1. Open your preferences from Menu *Preferences* > *Settings*
2. Add the following codes

#### Activation Codes

```
"color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - One Dark/One Dark.tmTheme",
"theme": "One Dark.sublime-theme",
"one_dark_sublime_text_2": true, // Only for Sublime Text 2
```

#### Recommended settings

```
"animation_enabled": false,
"caret_extra_bottom": 1,
"caret_extra_top": 2,
"caret_extra_width": 1,
"caret_style": "blink",
"draw_white_space": "none",
"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
"highlight_line": true,
"line_padding_bottom": 1,
"line_padding_top": 2,
"margin": 0,
"match_selection": false,
"tree_animation_enabled": false,
"scroll_past_end": false,
"show_definitions": false,
"show_tab_close_buttons": true, // mandatory to see unsaved files in tab
```

#### Optional settings

```
"one_dark_native_title_bar": true,          // only for Mac & Sublime Text 3 >= build 3127
"one_dark_show_scroll_tabs": true,          // only for Sublime Text 3
"one_dark_show_tabs_dropdown": true,        // only for Sublime Text 3
"one_dark_bigger_sidebar": true,            // uses font-size 14 for the sidebar
"one_dark_sidebar_font_fira_light": true,   // uses Fira Light for the sidebar
```

To get latest version of codes browse package [homepage](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20One%20Dark)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple steps for those on windows. It may work on other OS but haven't tested it.**

Firstly go [here](https://github.com/andresmichel/one-dark-theme/releases/tag/1.3.7) and download the `Source Code (zip) file`.

Then go to your Sublime packages directory, which should look like this

> C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages

You can find yours by clicking on the `Preference` and then `Browse Packages..`

Unzip the file downloaded file and paste it into your to your packages directory.

Once done simply go to 'Preferences' -> 'Colour Scheme' and find the folder there and select the theme you like, as illustrated below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made an adaptive One theme with Dark and Light One color schemes, it works for ST3 and ST4. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20One.